# Write array to a file with id?

Tags: php, arrays, fwrite

Can you help me to write selected values from a form to a file with their id. I have html form:

```
<form name="frm1" method="post" action="form_to_write.php">
    <h4>q1</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="someValue1" />someValue1<br />
    <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="someValue2" />someValue2<br />
    <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="someValue3" />someValue3
    <h4>q2</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="someValue4" />someValue4<br />
    <input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="someValue5" />someValue5<br />
    <input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="someValue6" />someValue6
    <h4>q3</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="someValue9" />someValue9<br />
    <input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="someValue7" />someValue7<br />
    <input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="someValue8" />someValue8
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

And my file `form_to_write.php` is:

```
$array = array_map("rtrim", $_POST['answer']);
$str = implode("\r\n", $array);
$date="date_not_work"; //date('m-d-y_H:i:s')
$fp = fopen($date."_out.txt", "w+");
$write=fwrite($fp, $str);
fclose($fp);

if ($write) echo 'Write is done!';
else echo 'Error!';
```

I need result in file like this:

```
1|value of 1
3|value of 3
2|value of 2
```

Now it write only values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = '';
foreach ($_POST['answer'] as $num => $answer) {
  $str .= "$num|$answer\r\n"; //i see no point in doing rtrim here
}
```

instead of

```
$array = array_map("rtrim", $_POST['answer']);
$str = implode("\r\n", $array);
```

as for the date, it's probably because of `:` symbols.

make it `"y-m-d_H-i-s"` format.
note the y-m-d order. this is way more reliable as it makes your files sortable by date

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know, why if I want to make output file name with a date (using `$date=date('m-d-y_H:i:s');`) - it isn't work?

Comment: see update. however, you have to be more descriptive. `"isn't work"` is not a good problem description.